# Determine file pairs in a directory, same name but different extensions

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm currently working on a **.NET 2.0** application and I got stuck while trying to loop through all files in a specific folder and determine its file pairs. *(Files with the same name but different extensions)*

Like:

- MyFile0001.jpg
- MyFile0001.mp3
- MyFile0001.txt

I'm interested in the filename extension, if they are available or not, that's why I created a class called "FileClass". At the end the file pairs will be added to a list `list.AddRange()`.

Her is my code example:

```
class FileClass
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public bool mp3 { get; set; }
    public bool txt { get; set; }
    public bool jpg { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<FileClass>();

    var dirConfig = new DirectoryInfo(@"New Folder");
    var allFiles = dirConfig.GetFiles("*");

    foreach (var fileInfo in allFiles)
    {
        // Some code for finding file pairs...
        // set properties, if filename extension is available
        // and add them to a list. 
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to handle this?
*if possible without LINQ*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` (for filename -> list of extensions)
The first step could look like this:

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var dirConfig = new DirectoryInfo(@"SomeFolder");
var allFiles = dirConfig.GetFiles("*");
foreach (var fileInfo in allFiles)
{
     String coreName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name);
     if (!d.ContainsKey(coreName)) d.Add(coreName, new List<String>());
     d[coreName].Add(fileInfo.Extension);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
class FileClass
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public bool mp3 { get; set; }
    public bool txt { get; set; }
    public bool jpg { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<FileClass>();

    var dirConfig = new DirectoryInfo(@"New Folder");
    var allFiles = dirConfig.GetFiles("*");

    foreach (var fileInfo in allFiles)
    {
        // for purposes of matching files with different extensions,
        // the "fileName" variable below is the file name minus the extension
        var fileName = fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.Length
            - fileInfo.Extension.Length);
        var fileClass = list.Where(fc => fc.FileName == fileName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (fileClass == null)
        {
            // this is the first version of this file name,
            // so create a new FileClass instance and add it to the list
            fileClass = new FileClass({
                FileName = fileName,
                filePath = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, fileName),
                mp3 = (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".mp3"),
                txt = (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".txt"),
                jpg = (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
            });
            list.Add(fileClass);
        }
        else
        {
            // a different version of this file was already found,
            // so just set the boolean flag for this extension
            switch (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower()) {
                case ".mp3": fileClass.mp3 = true; break;
                case ".txt": fileClass.txt = true; break;
                case ".jpg": fileClass.jpg = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
string[] arrayOfFiles= Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "Filename.*");
```